# CheckBox binding to element issue in WP8.1

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I have a simple XAML:

```
      <CheckBox x:Name="chkShowGrid" IsThreeState="False" IsChecked="False">Show content</CheckBox>

      <Grid Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=chkShowGrid}">
      <TextBlock>Some content goes here</TextBlock>
      </Grid>
```

This XAML works well in WinRT Windows 8.1 application. When I trying it in WP8.1 application it works in designer (shows or hides grid depend of checkbox value), but not on the phone. Why?

UPDATE:
I have universal 8.1 app and if use converter then shows me exception:

> error CS0012: The type 'Type' is defined in an assembly that is not
>   referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime,
>   Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

Converter code:

```
       class BoolConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            if (value == null) return false;

            return (bool)value;
        }
        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }    
}
```

In XAML

```
 <Page.Resources>
    <local:BoolConverter x:Name="ThatsMyConverter"/>
</Page.Resources>
```

........

```
<Grid Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=chkShowSettings,Converter={StaticResource ThatsMyConverter}}">
```

Comment: Try binding the IsChecked property through a converter to Visibility. That may be the problem!

Comment: Converter shows the exception

Comment: Do you reference your converter namespace at the beginning of your xaml file, and add the converter as a static resource? That should be done to make it work

Comment: Yes, I have did it. And in converter I can't get value. I have update question with exception from converter

Comment: Please post the code of the converter, also update your xaml how you use the converter. Maybe we can figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your converter returns a boolean value and you are trying to assign a bool to Visibility which can only take Visible or Collapsed as possible values. Try returning Visibility from your converter instead of bool. That should work. For example in your converter:

```
if (value == null) return Visibility.Collapses;
   var val = (value as bool);
   if (val)
       return Visibility.Visible;
    else
       return Visibility.Collapsed;
```

Comment: It works thanks! Simple solution, but I was confused why in WinRT and in designer everything works without conversion